# Create a hash containing arrays

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hashmap

I am trying to create a hash called winners.

I have a model called `arcade` each even has `games` associated with it. I am trying to create a hash of winners that is matched to each prize.

`arcade.rb` is:

```
def prizes_by winner
  winners = {}
  self.games.each do |g|
   high_score = g.high_score
   if high_score
     winners[high_score.user] ||= []
     winners[high_score.user] << g
   end
  end
end
```

When I get the hash back it doesn't contain the key for each `high_score.user`.

I expect a hash that looks like:

```
winners{
   user1 => [game1, game2, game3...]
   user2 => [game 4]
   user3 => [game10, game11]
   ...
}
```

Comment: What is the use of `winner` parameter?

Comment: @WandMaker I just fixed that it was supposed to be high_score

Comment: What hash do you expect, example?

Comment: @sschmeck I provided that at the bottom of the question

Comment: What does the hash actually contain? This looks like it should work

Comment: When you say `it doesn't contain the key for each high_score.user` - do you mean those users belonged to current arcade?  Should you be using `Game.all` instead of `self.games`?

Comment: @Dbz I think I figured out my problem, for some reason the hash was only containing the values not the key, so at the end I just returned winners and it seems to be working now

Comment: When you present a question it is important to first explain what you are trying to accomplish, preferably in words, preferably with an example. Instead you are asking the reader to figure out what you are trying to by studying your code. This question begs for an example at the beginning. When you provide an example, make it self-contained (no `...` or `etc.`), and compact as possible, assign a variable to each input object (so readers can cut-and-paste and refer to the variables in comments and answers without having to define them), and show the desired result.

Comment: Please read "[ask]" and "[mcve]". We need to see the minimal code that demonstrates the problem, along with the minimum data necessary to test that code. As is we can't run it and we have to dissect your code to figure out the data, which wastes our time and slows our answers.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this? Using [`each_with_object`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object):

```
def prizes_by winner
  games.each_with_object({}) do |game, hash|
    if high_score = game.high_score
      (hash[high_score.user] ||= []).push(game)
    end
  end
end
```

I haven't tested this.